# Pass variables from HTML form to Perl script

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I'm having some difficulty creating an HTML front-end for a Perl script we use in-house for config generation. We've moved from a Linux system to a Windows server instance and I've tested CGI/Perl are working as expected. The script itself uses the following format:

```
my $unitname; #name of device
my $clientid; #name of client
my $version;  #version of device firmware
```

These variables are called via command line, which prints the config to the cli:

```
./confgen.pl -u "unitname" -c "clientid" -v "version"
```

What I am trying to acheive is to use the existing variables in an HTML Form, but am not having any luck. So far I have this:

```
<form action confgen.pl method "get">
    <input type="text" name="unitname">
    <input type="text" name="clientid">
    <input type="text" name="version">
    <input type="submit" Value="generate"
</form>
```

Any advice or examples? I should add that CGI and Perl aren't my first languages, but I've been trying my best.

Comment: that can't be how your script looks; how does it read the command-line arguments?  also your HTML is missing some `=` and a `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be like this

```
<form action="confgen.pl" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="unitname">
    <input type="text" name="clientid">
    <input type="text" name="version">
    <input type="submit" value="generate">
</form>
```

are you using any Perl library to receive the HTTP request? Consider using CGI
http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: that link is, as its name says, about _sending_ an HTTP request from Perl, not _receiving_ one.